# Android BLE read data rate is slow when device is paired

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am developing an Android BLE app which sends multiple read requests per second (~ 10 samples/second). I have noticed that when the ble device is paired (bonded) to the phone, the reading rate is slow (~ 1 sample/sec), while the read rate is good (~ 10 samples/sec) when the blue device is unpaired (not bonded).

Is there any reason for this?!! Does pairing affects the data rate? and if so, why?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the device is requesting for a change in [Connection Interval](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/technical-considerations) after pairing, to save power.

Comment: yea, it works fine on Android 5.0 and later - call 'requestConnectionPriority' with CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH parameter -, but till now can't find a solution for Android less than 5.0 !!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Android API support. But it seems it should work on 4.3 or higher. If you have access to the device S/W, you could try configuring the device to request shorter connection intervals. Although it is upto Android to Accept /Reject those parameters, assuming Android is the central in this scenario.